# filter adding search bar to MultiplePushRow in eureka form builder in swift

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I'm working on iOS forms using one of the top form builder framework [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) I am looking for filter/search solution on `MultipleSelectorRow` control currently it does not have that feature. Does anyone customized this plugin ? How to go about it ?

```
Import Eureka

MultipleSelectorRow<String>() {
                $0.title = "Tags"
                $0.selectorTitle = "Choose"
                $0.options = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4"]
                $0.tag = "strTags"
                }.onPresent { from, to in
                    to.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: from, action: #selector(self.multipleSelectorDone(_:)))
        } .cellUpdate { cell, row in
                    if (row.value != nil) {
                        cell.detailTextLabel?.text =  row.value!.joined(separator: ", ")
                    }
        }
```

looking customization on the above control

Comment: Did you achieve search here?

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/gotelgest/cf309f6e2095ff22a20b09ba5c95be36

This might help as it's working for push row. Search is implemented for push row here. Little modification here can figure out your solution.